# AppleScriptからNightShiftのON/OFFを操作したい

Tags: applescript

AppleScriptからNightShiftのON/OFFを操作したいと思っています。

- 明日までONにするというところのCheckboxの操作の仕方がわからない
- UIの取得の仕方が分からない

ご教授いただければ幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
      tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
      end tell

      delay 0.5

      tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            try
                click button "Night Shift" of window 1

            end try
        end tell
      end tell

      delay 0.5

      tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        close window 1
      end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    tell application "System Preferences" to reveal ¬
        pane "com.apple.preference.displays"


    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences" to tell ¬
            window 1 to set _T to ¬
            a reference to tab group 1

        repeat until _T exists
            delay 1
        end repeat

        tell _T
            click radio button 3 -- "Night Shift"
            click checkbox 1 -- "Turn On Until Later Today"
        end tell
    end tell

    quit application "System Preferences"
```

Comment: CJK様。無事操作できました、非常に助かりました。誠にありがとうございます。